# Design of Java-Excel on server

Tags: java, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that has a lot of macros which do calculation. My goal is to have users be able to use a java program on their computer which somehow transfer data to my server and this server put values in the spreadsheet, runs the macro, get the value generated in the spreadsheet and send it back to the user.

I have the following solution in mind and I would appreciate if you can confirm if this right or you suggest a better solution?

I will have a Java program running on Windows server. It has an open socket and listening to connections. Once connection accepted, it will receive the user data from user machine, it will put the values in the spreadhseet using JExcelApi and then it will invoke .bat file that will startup Excel with the spreadsheet. As soon as excel opens, it will run the macro generate the results and close itself. "somehow" the java program has to be notified and grab the data from the spreadsheet and send it back to the user.

Does this make sense? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems like a reasonable approach to me. When you mentioned the 'somehow' in regards to notifying the java program, your best approach would probably just to be to try to have the .bat file output the results of the excel macro (not totally 100% on this one since I've never integrated the two) to the stdout stream, which you'll have access to after using the Runtime.exec() command to start the .bat file. Once that result is outputted you could have a thread listening for it, and then do some operations with it.

Good luck! It doesn't sound like a terribly simple problem, but with some perverseness you'll come out with a neat solution I have no doubt.